# How to save and restore an audiounit's state as an audiounit host

Tags: hosting, core-audio, audiounit

I am writing an app that hosts apple system supplied audiounits. I would like to save the parameter states of an audiounit after a user has dialed them in and restore them when the user loads the audiounit again.

I can't find out to do this from a host. I've seen that AUs should have SaveState() and RestoreState() methods, but how do you access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you handle them by getting or setting the `kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo` property with `AudioUnitGetProperty()` or `AudioUnitSetProperty()` (for saving and restoring, respectively).

You can see an example implementation of this in the [DestroyFX Audio Unit utilities library](http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/dfx-au-utilities.html) in the methods `RestoreAUStateFromPresetFile()` and `SaveAUStateToPresetFile_Bundle()` in the [dfx-au-utilities-preset-files.c](http://destroyfx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/destroyfx/trunk/dfx-library/dfx-au-utilities-preset-files.c?revision=1099&view=markup) file.